# Flex integration problem

Tags: apache-flex, flash

have 3 swf files.
1. a preloader
2. a screen-wide menu
3. a photo gallery
(coding in as3)
Each of these files individually is not very large in size. But all this together might be.

My Question:

1. Can I import all 3 files in flex and this happen:
   user click on the preloader, leads to the screen-wide menu. and depending on the button clicked on the menu, the appropriate picture gallery is loaded?
   in a manner such that each object loaded dynamically
2. Can I display 2 swf files like one file over the other... like z-index in css.
   Eg: a small right-hand corner floating menu on the corner which bloats up on rollover floating across the screen on top of the screen-wide menu?

PS: I am new to Flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically load any number of SWFs from within your Flex project.  As well, based on interactions with each SWF you can load another SWF.

Check out the [Loader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Loader.html) class for information about usage and events to listen to.

Comment: I don't think you got my question correctly.
1. I want a swf floating over another
2. I want on_Click(Button1) in a.swf to go to a part in b.swf and on_Click(Button2) in a.swf to go to another part in b.swf

Comment: You can layer swfs inside of flex, exactly as you can layer flex controls.  It would take additional work in the main flex app, but you can talk back and forth between each SWF and the main flex app.  So a.swf can through an event for on_click(Button1) and the main flex app can catch that event and then tell b.swf to do something.  To be honest, it would probably save you some time (and confusion) to redo some or all of the SWFs right inside of Flex